# Web Response Error 500

Tags: vb.net, webservice, vb, response

Buen día comunidad, actualmente se me está presentando un inconveniente al consumir un `webservice` desde VB.Net. Al momento de realizar el `request` no se me presenta ningún inconveniente, pero al momento de querer obtener el `response` me muestra un error 500 `Error en el servidor remoto: (500) Error interno del servidor.`. Está claro lo que muestra el error, pero al momento de usar `SoapUI` para consumir el servicio este me responde de manera correcta, anexo mi código:

```
Private Function SendSoapMessage(ByVal urlRQ As String, ByVal pXmlRq As XmlDocument, ByVal pXmlRs As XmlDocument) As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean = False
    Dim request As WebRequest
    Dim postData As String = String.Empty

    Try
        request = WebRequest.Create(urlRQ)
        request.Method = "POST"

        Dim byteArray As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pXmlRq.InnerXml())
        request.ContentType = "application/xml"
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length

        Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
        dataStream.Close()

        //Aquí se genera el error, justo al ejecutar esta línea donde declaro el response
        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()//<--------------
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()

        Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
        Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()

        pXmlRs.LoadXml(responseFromServer)

        dataStream.Close()
        result = True
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    Return result
End Function
```

¿A caso hay algo mal en la declaración?.. o ¿Que puede estar generando el error en mi código que en SoapUI no se me presenta?.

Agradezco cualquier comentario al respecto. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya resolví el inconveniente, resulta que al momento de tomar una respuesta generaba el `error 500` debido a que así lo tienen programado en el `webservice`, lo que hice fue obtener la respuesta en el `catch` y verificar el contenido:

```
Catch ex As WebException
            If Not ex.Response Is Nothing Then
                Dim data As StreamReader = New StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream)
'Al asignar el data.ReadToEnd al string se puede apreciar la respuesta del WebService en la variable str
                Dim str As String = data.ReadToEnd

            End If

        End Try
```

En resumen, el código no estuvo incorrecto, si no que el mismo `webservice` genera el `error 500` para informar que la respuesta es negativa y envía esa respuesta de vuelta como "error".

Espero esto le beneficie a alguien más.